# Why do we need continuity in this theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis

> The integral $\int_\gamma f dz$, with continuous $f$, depends only on the end points of $\gamma$ if and only if $f$ is the derivative of an analytic function in $\Omega$.

Why do we need the continuity of $f$?

Should I think of the theorem as these two parts:

(1) If $f$ is continuous and it is the derivative of an analytic function in $\Omega$, then the integral $\int_\gamma f dz$ depends only on the end points.

(2) If $f$ is continuous and the integral $\int_\gamma f dz$ depends only on the end points of $\gamma$, then $f$ has an antiderivative in $\Omega$?

Comment: If you take the function $f$ that is $1$ on the rationals and $0$ on the irrationals, then $\int_\gamma f \, dz$ depends only on the endpoints of $\gamma$ since the integral is always $0$, but it is not the derivative of an analytic function.

Comment: Continuity is redundant in part (1); the derivative of an analytic function is itself analytic. It is necessary in part (2), as @JairTaylor's example shows.

Comment: You could also set $f = 1$ at some point $x \in \Omega$ and $0$ everywhere else, since you need to have the Lebesgue integral for the first example.

Comment: @anomaly True, but this problem is accessible well before that result is proved.